# OpenCV for OSX: OpenCL Concerns

Tags: macos, opencv, opencl

I am currently working on an OSX application that requires my team to use OpenCV, and we are thinking of utilizing the GPU in order to speed up some of our calculations. I am not familiar using the GPU when it comes to OpenCV, more so that we're working on an Apple/UNIX environment (I mostly used OpenCV in Windows/python back in my college freshman years). Will building OpenCV 3 with OpenCL be a safe bet? Does OpenCV even play nice with the GPU using OpenCL?

I've read from this [blog](https://fogofcode.wordpress.com/2014/02/23/running-opencv-on-osx-with-opencl-support/) that OpenCV doesn't fully support OpenCL in OSX, but that was written nearly three years ago, so I'm not sure if that is still applicable today. Also, I don't think CUDA is not an option since we're working on Apple machines. I apologize for the noobish question in advance.

Thank you.

Comment: OpenCV has great support for GPU computation. OpenCL or CUDA depends on which type of GPU you've on your machine. If Nvidia then definitely go with CUDA, for everything else OpenCL.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the response! So it seems that OpenCL is a good blanket case that will cover most Mac GPUs then? Reason I'm asking is that Nvidia cards also support OpenCL, as far as I know. Since our target platform is OSX, using CUDA in OpenCV is out of the question for us.